# Form submission returning error but not showing error in the log

Tags: 2010, error

A user is getting the following error when submitting a form in SP2010.

[image: Error Details]

When I run Get-SPLogEvent it returns the following:

```
Category                   Message
Logging Correlation Data   Name=Request (POST:http://mypackimpex:80/sites/IT/_layouts/NWInitForm1/NWInitForm1Page.aspx?List=%7B5CCFAAA5%2D6F15%2D4D21%2D983D%2D7A2814CF267A%7D&ID=7601&TemplateID=c1175880-7c36-4745-a4f6-ecba9acab757&Source=http%3A%2F2Fmypackimpex%2Fsites%2FIT%2FSitePages%2Fmovewaresupport%2Easpx)                 
Logging Correlation Data   Site=/sites/IT
Publishing                 Setting [Display] as the FormContext.FormMode for the current page
Monitoring                 Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://mypackimpex:80/sites/IT/_layouts/NWInitForm1/NWInitForm1Page.aspx?List=%7B5CCFAAA5%2D6F15%2D4D21%2D983D%2D7A2814CF267A%7D&ID=7601&TemplateID=c1175880-7c36-4745-a4f6-ecba9acab757&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fmypackimpex%2Fsites%2FIT%2FSitePages%2Fmovewaresupport%2Easpx)). Execution Time=181.0684
```

This looks as though there is no error, at least not associated with that Correlation ID.

This doesn't happen every time, just once in a while.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Is the form in InfoPath? Have you updated the InfoPath parameters to match that of the list?

Comment: @Mike No i think it is a custom form. For some reason it is in the layouts folder in the hive. If I go to the form page in Sharepoint, I get no options to edit it or anything.